# Multi-Threading Starting Time

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a multi-threading code running on my asp.net app like follow:

```
...
List<Thread> workers = new List<Thread>();
foreach (Airline airline in this._criteria.Airlines)
{
    Task mytask = new Task();
    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(mytask.Execute));
    workers.Add(t);
    t.Start();
}

//block all until finish
foreach (var t in workers)
{
    t.Join();
}

...
```

This code is work fine on one of server(windows2003, 32bit) and a great speed.
But when i moved it to the new server, windows2008 64bit, I found that all tasks didn't start concurrence as well.

Here is starting time for each tasks on both server:
  - Rqst = time when task start
  - Resp = time when task done

----------------------- server 2:  64bit windows 2008 -----------------
*you'll see that starting time of each task (first started on 01:12:55.233 and last started on 01:13:11.773)

26230    2009-12-29 01:13:12.953    5812        Resp
26229    2009-12-29 01:13:11.773    5812        Rqst

26228    2009-12-29 01:13:05.453    616        Resp
26220    2009-12-29 01:13:00.213    616        Rqst

26227    2009-12-29 01:13:02.843    5792        Resp
26224    2009-12-29 01:13:01.653    5792        Rqst

26225    2009-12-29 01:13:01.873    4136        Resp
26221    2009-12-29 01:13:00.657    4136        Rqst

26226    2009-12-29 01:13:02.433    4932        Resp
26223    2009-12-29 01:13:01.150    4932        Rqst

26222    2009-12-29 01:13:00.910    5096        Resp
26219    2009-12-29 01:12:59.813    5096        Rqst

26217    2009-12-29 01:12:56.703    3332        Resp
26216    2009-12-29 01:12:55.303    3332        Rqst

26218    2009-12-29 01:12:56.703    3768        Resp
26215    2009-12-29 01:12:55.233    3768        Rqst

------------------------ server1: windows 2003 -----------------

26129    2009-12-29 01:11:44.107    5056        Resp
26126    2009-12-29 01:11:42.950    5056        Rqst

26130    2009-12-29 01:11:44.107    7368        Resp
26127    2009-12-29 01:11:42.967    7368        Rqst

26128    2009-12-29 01:11:44.090    5548        Resp
26125    2009-12-29 01:11:42.933    5548        Rqst

26120    2009-12-29 01:11:42.887    8100        Resp
26117    2009-12-29 01:11:41.637    8100        Rqst

26121    2009-12-29 01:11:42.887    7640        Resp
26116    2009-12-29 01:11:41.623    7640        Rqst

26122    2009-12-29 01:11:42.887    7780        Resp
26119    2009-12-29 01:11:41.700    7780        Rqst

26123    2009-12-29 01:11:42.887    1868        Resp
26115    2009-12-29 01:11:41.543    1868        Rqst

26118    2009-12-29 01:11:41.670    5936        Resp
26124    2009-12-29 01:11:42.887    5936        Rqst

Is there anything wrong in my code or it's about the difference platforms?
Thanks

Comment: Is the hardware architecture of the two machines the same?  If the second (64-bit) system is multi-core, that could be a factor.

Comment: Oh, and also, is the 2008 server R1 or R2?  R1 is ServerVista, while R2 is ServerWin7.  Big differences between the two.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but a strong suggestion:  You should really consider using the async framework built-in to asp.net.  You can queue multiple items without causing your Request thread to block and wait.  You will have speed AND better concurrency with very little extra code to write.

Comment: Did that last request move back in time?

Answer (score 1):

I think the stack size for threads on the x64 is larger than 1Mb like it was on Windows 2003 x86. Try using the threadpool instead to reduce the cost of creating new threads.

In addition, the new IIS on Windows 2008 might (I'm not sure) throttle how fast threads can be generated.